# If a mix of elements in a plasma are frozen rapidly, does the crystalline structure of the frozen material reflect the plasma phase?

Tags: plasma-physics

If you have a mix of elements in a plasma, with ions flying around freely, and you freeze it, would you see reflections of that plasma phase in the crystalline structure of the frozen material? Plasma tends to organize into plasmoids and helices, would that be reflected after freezing?

Answer (score 3):

No. In the process of cooling the plasma down, the positive and negative ions it is composed of would recombine and revert to just being a cloud of very hot gas. Cool that further and it would condense into a very cold liquid; cool it still more and (depending on what it is made from) it would freeze into a solid. At each stage of this freezing process, whatever structure there might have existed in the previous phase gets erased as the new phase forms.

Comment: if multiple elements, could the ions (when cooled) recombine in new ways to form crystalline structures other than before it was excited?

Comment: it depends on the rate of cooling and what exactly the elements were. Hard question to answer.

Comment: cytosol within a living cell, and, flash-frozen, instantaneous (very rapid)

Comment: centrioles have structures within them that have been unexplained for 50 years. I had the idea that they may reflect plasma self-organization, the "central vesicle" a plasmoid, and the surrounding helix plasma filaments in a helix. that hypothesis hinges on wether or not the plasma phase would be reflected after flash-freezing the cell prior to electron photography,
https://www.docdroid.net/ad803Bk/architecture-and-function-of-the-mammalian-centriole.pdf